# How can I create a new account or address with web3.js?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

I'm trying to interact with `geth`, and I need to create a new deposit address (and be able to control it). How can I implement this with web3.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create new accounts with web3:

`web3.eth.personal.newAccount('yourpassword')`

This will return the new address. for details go [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-personal.html#newaccount)